# How to extract a table from the website using python?

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, datatable, extract

I wrote a code to extract table from this website (http://www.nhb.gov.in/OnlineClient/MonthlyPriceAndArrivalReport.aspx), but I am unable to do so.

```
from selenium import webdriver 
import time, re
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
import time

chrome_path = r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)

driver.get("http://www.nhb.gov.in/OnlineClient/MonthlyPriceAndArrivalReport.aspx")

html_source = driver.page_source
results=[]

#cauliflower
element_month = driver.find_element_by_id ("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlmonth")
drp_month = Select(element_month)
drp_month.select_by_visible_text("January")

element_category_name = driver.find_element_by_id ("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_drpCategoryName")
drp_category_name = Select(element_category_name)
drp_category_name.select_by_visible_text("VEGETABLES")

time.sleep(2)
element_crop_name = driver.find_element_by_id ("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_drpCropName")
drp_crop_name = Select(element_crop_name)
drp_crop_name.select_by_value("117")
time.sleep(2)
element_variety_name = driver.find_element_by_id ("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlvariety")
drp_variety_name = Select(element_variety_name)
drp_variety_name.select_by_value("18")

element_state = driver.find_element_by_id ("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_LsboxCenterList")
drp_state = Select(element_state)
drp_state.select_by_visible_text("AHMEDABAD")

driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnSearch"]""").click()

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
table = pd.read_html(driver.page_source)[3]
#number three is arbitrary. I tried all numbers from 1 to 6 and python did not recognize the table at 
#the bottom of the screen. 
print(len(table))
print(table)
with pd.ExcelWriter(r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\python.xlsx') as writer:
 table.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = "cauliflower", index=False) # cauliflower results on sheet named 
 cauliflower
 writer.save()
```

Can you please help me figure out how to extract the table at the bottom of the website. Your help will be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you getting any error, please include that in your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that without using Beautiful soup. After click on search button.

Induce `WebDriverWait`() and wait for `visibility_of_element_located`()
Get the table element using `get_attribute('outerHTML')`

Then use `pd.read_html(str(tableelement))[0]` and `print(table)`

Rest you can do that to import in excel or csv.

**Code**:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnSearch']").click()
tableelement=WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"table#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridViewmonthlypriceandarrivalreport"))).get_attribute('outerHTML')
table = pd.read_html(str(tableelement))[0]
print(table)
```

You need to import below libraries.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

---

If you want to use `BeautifulSoup` as well then try this code.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnSearch']").click()
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"table#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridViewmonthlypriceandarrivalreport")))
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
table = pd.read_html(str(soup))[-1]
print(table)
```

**Output**:

```
  S.No.            CenterName  ...         Day30         Day31
0    1.0  AHMEDABAD / अहमदाबाद  ...  1.002502e+15  2.005004e+15
1    NaN                   NaN  ...           NaN           NaN

[2 rows x 35 columns]
```